# What does Log N complexity actually entail?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I know what log n complexity usually entails in practice (binary search, looking up a person in a phone book and breaking it down smaller and smaller instead of going through A to Z, divide and conquer) but I'm still not sure from a mathematical/computational standpoint **what and why a certain process is said to have a time complexity of log n.**

Comment: For the formal definition: look at [Big Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations), replace f with the time needed to compute the result, and replace g with log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on big O notation on other websites that explain it well, instead of asking on StackOverflow.

**Disclaimer this is very simplified explanation, for general explanation you should look into big O definition.**

As for why is binary search `O(log n)`. It boils down to the number of operations you perform. For arrays of lengths you need to perform:

`len: 0, ops: 1`
`len: 1, ops: 1`
`len: 2, ops: 2`
`len: 3, ops: 2`
`len: 4, ops: 3`
`len: 5, ops: 3`
`len: 6, ops: 3`
`len: 7, ops: 3`
`len: 8, ops: 4`
`...`
`len: 16, ops: 5`
`...`

In each iteration you can perform `1` operation and repeat the binary search on array with lenght half the size. That's where the logarithm comes from. For array of length `2^n`, you need at most `log_2 n` operations.

Answer (score 0):

One clear example of `log(n)` complexity is traversing a rooted tree from root to one of its leaf (like binary search as you've mentioned). If you have `n` objects from which you want to create a balanced rooted tree, the height of this tree will be `log(n)`. Because a binary balanced tree has `2^h` nodes in maximum (`h` is the height of the tree), and if you solve `n = 2^h`, you will find that height of the tree, `h`, should be `log(n)`.

In sum, most of the time in regular algorithms, the provenance of `log(n)` in complexity comes from the traversing a balanced rooted tree (or generally a rooted tree), from its root to one of its leaf in a top-down approach.